# How to install Vagrant on Linux RHEL server

Tags: linux, vagrant, rhel

I have to install Vagrant on Linux RHEL server. But somehow I couldn't manage to get any Vagrant installable available for Linux RHEL server on their site.

Please let me know if you have any idea about the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For RedHat series, you should be able to download the RPM from vagrant site directly, for the latest version (currently 1.9.2) its https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/1.9.2/vagrant_1.9.2_x86_64.rpm?_ga=1.16662838.1064717159.1478512035 (for 64 bits) or https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/1.9.2/vagrant_1.9.2_i686.rpm?_ga=1.4161840.1064717159.1478512035 (for 32 bits)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Henri. Any idea if its free even for production environment?

Comment: vagrant open-source and has MIT license so you're free to use - its not recommended to use it in Production mode though, its really meant to be used by dev to work in environement that replicates the prod env